# Is it possible to get the clicked element that triggers a route change from the Vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a button that triggers a route change within my Vue application. I want the button element to be accessible in the component's $route object as the "event target" of the route change (similar to how there's an event.target in a click event).

Is that possible?

If not, what would be the best way to obtain the cause of the route change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html). There are

- [Global navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) that are called on each route
  beforeEnter/resolve/leave/after depending on the type of guard you
  used.
- [Per-route navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard) that are used in your
  router file, inside each route's declaration.
- [In-Component
  Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) that are used inside components.

You can get the specific button that caused the route change in your component inside the In-Component Guard `beforeRouteLeave(to, from)`. This specific guard has access to `this` of the component which has all the props and reactive state (including the button reference).

---

##### According to the docs, this is how each guard falls in the **flow of a navigation** action:

- Navigation triggered.
- Call `beforeRouteLeave` guards in deactivated components.
- Call global `beforeEach` guards.
- Call `beforeRouteUpdate` guards in reused components.
- Call `beforeEnter` in route configs.
- Resolve async route components.
- Call `beforeRouteEnter` in activated components.
- Call global `beforeResolve` guards.
- Navigation is confirmed.
- Call global `afterEach` hooks.
- DOM updates triggered.
- Call callbacks passed to next in `beforeRouteEnter` guards with instantiated instances.